# Subqueries OK on MySQL but not on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery

The query hereunder :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.rowid
FROM llx_negoce_commandes AS c
LEFT JOIN llx_negoce_semaines AS s ON c.rowid = s.fk_negoce_commande
WHERE c.entity = 2
  AND
    (SELECT count(s.rowid)
     WHERE (CONCAT(s.annee, LPAD(s.semaine, 2, '0')) <= '202233')
       AND (CONCAT(s.annee, LPAD(s.semaine, 2, '0')) >= '202229')) > 0
  AND c.statut = 2
ORDER BY c.dossier DESC
```

works perfectly well on MySQL 5.7. But executed on MariaDB 10.3.35, I have an error saying :

```
#1064 - Syntax error near 'WHERE (CONCAT(s.annee,LPAD(s.semaine,2,'0')) <= '202233') > 0 AND (CONCAT(s.a...' at line 1
```

Does anybody know deeply the differences between those databases systems to understand what's wrong with MariaDB ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT` needs a `FROM` statement where there is a `WHERE`. You can fake it by using `FROM dual` in the inner query. I'm not sure its generating the result you think it is.  Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN` and put subquery `WHERE` with the `WHERE` of the outer query and remove the subquery.

Comment: The portion of the query displayed within the syntax error doesn't appear within the original query you posted.

Comment: Upgrade mariadb to 10.4 or above? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=dda0d688d8b8689b136c8eb9a87e4559 btw query will fail in 5.7 if only_full_group_by is set. You should not regard mariadb as a drop in replacement for mysql - there are just too many differences now.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.
Use of DUAL actually works fine and allows to avoid errors on MariaDB whithout need of changing version.